# How to change scaling in color key in heatmap.2?

Tags: r, heatmap

Is there a way to change the color key scale so that values are binned by quantity? For example I have 15 values going from 0-1, and only a few values going from 1 to less than 8. But because my range is 0-8 the scale is so off and a huge chunk of my colours are stuck on the left end of the scale whereas most of it remains red. See image.[image]

Here is my dataset used to generate the heatmap below. It is saved to a CSV file.

```
GeneID  Habitat1    Habitat2    Habitat3    Control
Gene1   0.135   0.248   0.143   0.272
Gene2   0.16    0.455   0.233   0.602
Gene3   0.152   0.08    0.15    0.62
Gene4   4.86    2.93    6.035   3.56
Gene5   0   2.993   4.464   0.356
Gene6   0.071   3.805   6.82    0.587
Gene7   0.46    2.828   3.097   6.45
Gene8   0.92    3.901   3.042   5.58
```

Here is my R code:

```
x <- read.csv("heatmapvals_generated.csv", header=TRUE, row.names="GeneID") #snippet from a much larger dataset to create the mini heatmap image, but the number ranges are about the same. Mostly from 0-1 and then a few >1.
y <- data.matrix(x)
colors = c(seq(0,0.018,length=5),
           seq(0.019,0.98,length=50), 
           seq(0.99,1.098,length=5),
           seq(1.099,3,length=20),
           seq(3.099,8,length=20))
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("navy","blue","grey","red","darkred"))(n=99)

hm2 <- heatmap.2(y, col=my_palette, trace="none", breaks=colors, margins=c(10,15),
                 scale="none", dendrogram = "none",
                 Colv=F, Rowv=F, cexRow = 1, cexCol=1.2, density.info="none")
```

I am not sure where I can change the color key scale so that it reads 0-1 and 1-8 equally, and the white (which is value 1) is centered. The actual heatmap is fine.

Comment: Which package does `heatmap.2()` come from?

Comment: The package comes from gplots

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. What is `y`?

Comment: Also, what if you change the `scale` argument from "none" to "row" or "column"?

Comment: y is my dataset from a loaded csv file. Won't be able to share it for privacy reasons.

Comment: Changing scale to row or column just messed up the heatmap but made the length of the scale bar more equal - except the colours are still skewed. It did center "1" but now most of the scale bar is just white.

Comment: You can always generate data that is reflective of your problem.

Comment: Okay let me try that! Then I will update my code